# Kubuntu 18.04 can't set default web browser

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, kde, settings, browser

Links in Telegram have been opening random apps (image viewer, Calibre, etc), so I checked *System Settings > Applications > Default Applications > Web Browser*.

Open URLs "in an application based on the contents of the URL" sounds like the culprit, so I changed to "in the following application (Firefox)".

However after leaving this screen or rebooting (both) the setting reverts:

[image: Image1]

I ran system settings from console, but I [couldn't see any obvious errors](https://hastebin.com/ijememuhix.rb).

**Update:**  I ran a fresh install of Kubuntu 18.04 in a virtual machine and tried this, with the same result. Did all available updates and rebooted, tried it again - same result - even though it was on a fresh, stock system.

Comment: I think this is a bug, and it's new in Kubuntu 18.04. This stuff used to work in Kubuntu 17.10 and 17.04.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what did you use to record the screen?

Comment: @ChristianHujer I believe it was SimpleScreen Recorder http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug appears to be resolved in 18.04.3

Answer (score 5):

Not ideal but I used the `with the following command:` option on Default Applications dialog in Kubuntu 18.04. For Firefox I would assume this would work: `/usr/bin/firefox %s`. I prefer Google Chrome so I used: `/usr/bin/google-chrome %s`

[image: Screenshot of Default Applications dialog in Kubuntu 18.04]

Answer (score 2):

What was helping me:
(I am using Kubuntu 18.04 LTS) find the following file
`/home/USERNAME/.config/mimeapps.list` and edit it like this:

```
[Default Applications]
application/x-desktop=doublecmd.desktop;
inode/directory=doublecmd.desktop;
inode/symlink=pcmanfm.desktop
text/html=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/http=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/https=google-chrome.desktop
```

The last two `x-scheme-handler/...` lines were empty for me, so I wrote google chrome there as I prefer chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue. It looks like a bug.

What helped me was clicking on "File Associations" after "Apply" and then again on "Default Applications". I noticed that my change was applied. After that I closed the settings window and opened it again. My change was still there.

PS: I could reproduce the issue even in 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue. For me, it was due to the file ~/.config/mimeapps.list not owned by me.
And it was the only file in this folder not owned by myself.
So I changed the file owner:

```
cd
cd .config/
sudo chown myUserName:myUserGroup mimeapps.list
```

And then I could update my default applications.