# How do I permanently set Firefox snap as default browser?

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, browser, 22.04, default

I've recently upgraded to Kubuntu 22.04.
I've attempted several times to set Firefox as the default browser in about:preferences without success.  I select 'Make default', then 'yes' to 'Allow settings change', but the message, 'Firefox is not your default browser' persists.

I've come across the following ticket about this same issue.  If I'm reading it correctly it was fixed four years ago.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1444313

---

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubuntu 18.04 can't set default web browser](https://askubuntu.com/q/1043324/) and [How do I change my default browser?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79305/how-do-i-change-my-default-browser)

Comment: It's a known bug. Three workarounds are offered by Snap developers https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/firefox-snap-cannot-be-set-as-default-browser/26636 until the bug is fixed.

Comment: That is normal behaviour of snap and flatpak firefoxes. They won't check if they are the default browser though when starting up.

Answer (score 4):

**2023-08-11 edit**: I guess this is solved on the Snap side, for sure on Ubuntu `22.04.*` and more.

There is a [PPA from Mozilla](https://launchpad.net/%7Emozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) existing. You can follow [this procedure](https://balintreczey.hu/blog/firefox-on-ubuntu-22-04-from-deb-not-from-snap/) to remove the `snap` and replace it by the Mozilla `.deb`.

It would solve the default browser issue by reverting you to the old package system, although the main `snap` problem still need to be solved on Snapcraft side.

Note: I am aware that it doesn't *solve* anything. From a user-centric point of view, it is the simplest method to make Firefox the default browser. I have nothing against snaps, and use them for many applications that are not available through packages. But Ubuntu's Firefox snap is just not well integrated yet. Hopefully, this situation won't last long.

Comment: Thank you @smonff, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

You can set it in the Settings app under [image: Default Applications]

Answer (score 1):

The [comment from user535733](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406843/how-do-i-permenently-set-firefox-snap-as-default-browser#comment2443691_1406843) deserves more visibility, in my opinion.

The `update-alternatives` mechanism is not yet integrated with snaps and don't know if there are plans for the near future.

According to the [snapcraft forum](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/firefox-snap-cannot-be-set-as-default-browser/26636), firefox can be set as default browser, using three alternative methods:

- from firefox itself, browsing to `about:preferences` and clicking the “Set default” button
- in a terminal, running `xdg-settings set default-web-browser firefox_firefox.desktop`
- in a GNOME desktop environment (not applicable in the OP specific use case), running `gnome-control-center default-apps` and selecting the entry for the firefox snap there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I've tried the first two without success.

Comment: Didn't work for me under Plasma either.

Comment: worked for me with KUbuntu

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. I think it is caused by two bugs in Firefox (snap package). I worked around it by:

1. Open preferences / go to `about:preferences` in Firefox
2. Disable "Always check if Firefox is your default browser", because Firefox (snap package) doesn't properly recognize if Firefox is set as default (Bug 1).

Checking "Don't ask me again" in the prompt on Firefox startup will also not disable this (Bug 2).

You might verify success e.g. by:

- type `xdg-settings get default-web-browser` in the terminal
- enter `http://example.org` in the file browser (Dolphin) address bar
- …

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (installing ubuntu 22.04, but using my old home directory from ubuntu 21.10).
Solution: Go to `system settings` --> `standard applications` --> `standard applications` --> `Webbrowser`. Change it from "Firefox" to "Firefox Web Browser" by using "other..." and search for "Firefox Web Browser" in the "internet"-section.

Comment: That way, for example when clicking on a web address in Konsole, instead of seeing an error about not finding `/usr/bin/firefox`... Firefox (which is in `/snap/bin/firefox`) is launched. OK.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the command line:

`sudo update-alternatives –config x-www-browser`

And select Firefox as the default browser.

Comment: This parameter is not available anymore on 22.04.

Comment: `update-alternatives` is for deb packages. It won't work with Snaps.